# Autohotkey, send Ctrl+R or Ctrl+Q to Quality Center is not working? Any Ideas

Tags: autohotkey, hp-quality-center

I am trying to automate some qc ( Quality Center ) tasks through Autohotkey.

Find below the code, It identifies and activates the QC > Test Run window, but after that the send keys function is not working. But the code is executed fully without any error and the final msgbox is displayed properly. Please help me !!

```
#V::
ifwinexist, Manual Runner
winactivate
Send ^R
msgbox, pass
```

Answer (score 1):

In your script, the `msgbox` has no relation to `winactivate` unless you put group the commands.

Your script is firing like this:

1. You push the hotkey.
2. it checks for the window
3. if the window exists, it activates it.
4. NOW - r gets sent no matter if #3 checked out or not!
5. The message box gets displayed no matter what happens.

Consider this, when you push the hotkey, nothing happens unless the window exists.  If the window exists, all of your commands will get processed.

```
#V::
ifwinexist, Manual Runner
{
    winactivate
    Send ^R
    msgbox, pass
}
return
```

If you have trouble sending the keys, you might look up `sendkeys` for some alternative methods:  `Send / SendRaw / SendInput / SendPlay / SendEvent`

Also, look at `setkeydelay`.

Another idea is to add `sleep 500` just after `winactivate`.

Comment: Hi, got your point. Now i have grouped the commands, and it activates the window, but the send command alone is not producing the result. Pretty confusing !!